# Custom validator and dinamic data in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, customvalidator

The first thing to say is that I have been searching for a long time, questions similar to the one I am going to ask and although I have found some, none have helped me with my problem. Having said this, I will explain the problem in question.

I am creating a custom validator for the file upload component. This validator must be able to validate the size of the files to be uploaded. At the moment I have this:

**file-validator.ts**

```js
export function fileSizeValidator(maxFileSize: number, files: any[]) {
  console.log(files)
  const maxFileSizeToKb = maxFileSize * 1024;
  return (): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    let forbidden = true;
    files.forEach(file => {
      if (file.file.size > maxFileSizeToKb) {
        forbidden = false;
      }
    });
    return forbidden ? { inValidSize: true } : null;
  };
}
```

**file-uploader.component.ts**

```js
...

ngOnInit() {
  this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    filesToUpload: ['', fileSizeValidator(this.data.maxMbSize, this.rawFiles)],
  });
  }

...
```

**file-uploader.component.html**

```html
...

<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
   <ng-container *ngIf="canUploadMultiple; else unique">
     <input #file formControlName="filesToUpload" type="file" [accept]="allowedFilesToString" (click)="fileInputClick($event)" id="{{fileId}}" name="file" multiple (change)="onUploadFile($event.target.files)" />
   </ng-container>
   <ng-template #unique>
     <input #file type="file" formControlName="filesToUpload" [accept]="allowedFilesToString" (click)="fileInputClick($event)" id="{{fileId}}" name="file" (change)="onUploadFile($event.target.files)"/>
   </ng-template>

...

 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!uploadForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

...
```

The problem is that when I add files to upload and the validator function is executed, the array of files always appears empty.

I have tried many things to make it work. I have tried to look for the value that I need inside the object `control: AbstractControl` that is passed to the function to see if from there I could find the array that is supposed to be passed to it when executing the validator function, but the only thing I find from array is the name of the files.

I have also tried to do a `.bind()` and an arrow function like this:

```js
this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    filesToUpload: ['', fileSizeValidator(this.data.maxMbSize, this.rawFiles).bind(this)],
  });
```

```js
this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    filesToUpload: ['', fileSizeValidator(this.data.maxMbSize, (() => this.rawFiles)],
  });
```

Another thing that I also thought might work is to put the validator back into the form once the dynamic array has been modified:

```js
...

this.rawFiles.push(this.formData.getAll('files'));
  this.uploadForm.controls['filesToUpload'].setValidators(Validators.compose([fileSizeValidator(this.data.maxMbSize, this.rawFiles)]));

...
```

But none of this works for me, I have tried other things that I have found on the internet, but they have not worked either. The only thing I can think of is to move the validator function from **file-validator.ts** to **files-uploader.component.ts** in order to have direct access to the dynamic array.

**Edit**: I tried that last option and dont't work too.

Comment: can you please provide a minimum reproduceable version of your code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? Also judging by the code you've shown, your validator is getting an array as param instead of reference to the file input html element, if you can pass that I think you'll be able to get the files chosen by user in validator

Comment: @Yogi Finally I made it all in "manual mode", setting the error when i need it. I can de reproducable on stackblitz but I do when i have a little more time...sorry for that and for try to help.

Comment: glad it worked out for you but just in case if anyone faces the same issue, heres a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-size-validator-angular-s6spk8?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) to create a custom file validator